# Automation using Bash

Tags: bash

We have total 168 sub directories all will end with doc_*_t extension where under these sub directories will have some files std_doc_*_t.lst, PA_doc_*_t_output.

So I need to check in all these sub directories is there any unseen modules in report.rpt for this I have created a small script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in *_t; 
do
    echo "$d"
    cat $d/PA_*_output/report.rpt | grep "Unseen Module"
    echo ""
done
```

Output of above script is:

```
doc_txa1_t
Number of Unseen Modules      = 4
smro                                   1               Unseen Module ( 1 )
mapo_HDN                               1               Unseen Module ( 1 )
trms7_cpo                              1               Unseen Module ( 1 )
overlay                                1               Unseen Module ( 1 )
Unseen Modules:
    Definition : Unseen Module (line 1) 
    Definition : Unseen Module (line 1) 

doc_fuse_t
Number of Unseen Modules      = 1
Unresolved Modules: 
TEF07HD18_PH_OVERLAY            4               Unseen Module ( 1 )
Unseen Modules: 
    Definition : Unseen Module (line 1)
```

Now I need to search these unseen modules(smro, mapo_HDN, trms7_cpo, overlay, TEF07HD18_PH_OVERLAY) in this path `/proj/history/Unseen_Modules` if these are available then we need to add below path in this file std_doc_*_t.lst which is available in all sub directories like below :

```
/proj/history/Unseen_Modules/TEF07HD18_PH_OVERLAY
/proj/history/Unseen_Modules/smro
/proj/history/Unseen_Modules/mapo_HDN
/proj/history/Unseen_Modules/trms7_cpo
/proj/history/Unseen_Modules/overlay
```

In above bash script can anyone please help me how can I do this after greping the Unseen Module and how I need to search those modules in this path /proj/history/Unseen_Modules/.
I tried this :

```
#!/bin/bash
path = /proj/history/Unseen_Modules
for d in *_t; 
do
    echo "$d"
    cat $d/PA_*_output/report.rpt | grep "Unseen Module"

done
```

I am stuck at how to search those modules in $path.

Comment: `cat $d/PA_*_output/report.rpt | grep "Unseen Module"` -> `grep "Unseen Module" "$d"/PA_*_output/report.rpt` | `path = /proj/history/Unseen_Modules` -> `path=/proj/history/Unseen_Modules` and `for d in "$path"/*/*_t`

Comment: @KamilCuk I didn't understood can you please make changes in my above code.